# ¿Cómo mejorar el resultado de pytesseract?

Tags: python, pytesseract

Estoy aplicando ***pytesseract*** a mi proyecto y no obtenía los resultados deseados, así que empecé a optimizar un poco...

- Entrené la font desde el sitio web
- Hice binaria la imagen (Blanco y
  negro)
- Puse únicamente los caracteres que tendrán las imágenes (A
  hasta Z en mayúscula)
- Ya que son de un solo carácter, puse en config *"--psm 10"*
- En una medida desesperada, con *Photoshop* **subí los DPI de 72 a 600**

Pero aún con todo esto y teniendo una clara letra aislada y visible, **en vez de la "A" obtengo una "T"**... ¿Hay algo dónde esté fallando? Realmente agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda :)

```
#Importar los modulos necesarios
import pytesseract
import pyautogui
import cv2
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'


#Leer la imagen
celda1 = cv2.imread('imagen.jpg')


# extraer texto de la imagen
sret=pytesseract.image_to_string(celda1, config="-c tessedit"
                                             "_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                             " --psm 10"
                                             " -l osd"
                                             " ")


# mostrar el resultado
print(sret)
```

[image: Imagen a analizar]

Answer (score 0):

Yo de igual manera estoy trabajando en algo así, mira tengo este código y me sirve parcialmente bien, aún falta pulir demasiado pero para comenzar esta bien. También te crea un archivo TXT que se llama "extraccion.txt". Se imprime el resultado tanto en consola y se Guarda en el TXT. Espero te sirva y si alguien puede mejorarlo me ayudaría mucho

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import os
import time

imagePath = "img15.jpg"
preprocess="thresh"

image= cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

if(preprocess=="thresh"):
 gray = cv2.threshold(gray,0,25,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
elif(preprocess=="blur"):
 gray = cv2.medianBblur(gray,3)

filename= "{}.jpg".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename,gray)

try:
 #Creación Archivo
 outfile='extraccion.txt' 
 f = open(outfile,"a") 
 img= Image.open(filename,mode = 'r')
 pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

 print("--------------------------")
 print("LISTO!!")
 print("--------------------------")
 print(text)
 print("--------------------------")

 #Guarda el Texto Reconocido en extraccion.txt
 f.write(text)
 f.close()
 cv2.imshow("Image",image)
 cv2.imshow("Output",gray)
 print("Press <ESC> para salir ")

 while (1):
  if(cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF==27):
   break
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 except IOError as e:
  print("I/O ERROR: "+str(e))
 except:
  print("OPss!! No se pudo reconocer")
```